# GPS is working but Distance is always showing 0. Can't calculate Distance in this code

Tags: nodemcu

```c++
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 5;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

TinyGPSPlus gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);
float temp1, temp2;

const char* ssid = "LYN TECH";
const char* password = "pass word";
const char* host = "your host name";
const int trigPin = 2; //D4
const int echoPin = 0; //D3
long duration;
int distance;
int t = 27;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    ss.begin(GPSBaud);

    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(100);
    //Serial.print("Connected to..");
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
}

void checkGPS()
{
    if (gps.charsProcessed() < 10) {
        Serial.println(F("No GPS detected: check wiring."));
    }
}

void loop()
{

    while (ss.available() > 0) {
        // sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
        if (gps.encode(ss.read()))
            if (gps.location.isValid()) {

                float latitude = (gps.location.lat()); //Storing the Lat. and Lon.
                temp1 = latitude;
                delay(2000);
                float longitude = (gps.location.lng());
                temp2 = longitude;
                delay(2000);

                Serial.print("LAT:  ");
                Serial.println(latitude, 6); // float to x decimal places

                Serial.print("LONG: ");
                Serial.println(longitude, 6);
            }
    }

    WiFiClient client;
    const int httpPort = 80;
    if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
        Serial.println("Connection failed");
        delay(1000);
        return;
    }

    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.println(distance);
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    String url = "your url.php?dist=" + String(distance) + "&lat=" + String(temp1, 6) + "&lng=" + String(temp2, 6);
    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                "Connection:close\r\n\r\n");
}
```

Comment: You never set `duration` to anything. Also... what? It looks like you're mixing ultrasonic range finding code in with your GPS system.

Comment: Exactly ! i have tried to merge ultrasonic code with my gps code. But i failed maybe ! GPS is working fine but distance can't calculation in this code.

Comment: Do you *have* an ultrasonic range finder?

Comment: am using ultrasonic sensor to measure distance .

Comment: So how about you actually read from it then?

Comment: Oh, and ditch those delays. There is no call to use delay where you use it. And introduce some concept of time into your sending of data, so you don't flood your web server.

Comment: in my code i have written how it will works...but unfortunately isn't working . Only gps portion is working. Can you plz rewrite it for me. so that i can test again. i have to must send value of measuring levels with gps data. plz help me..

Comment: >>> `You never set duration to anything.` ...

Comment: can you please rewrite it for me so that i can test again .

Comment: No, I can't. Just add in the missing code. The line that you didn't copy over from wherever you found the code. The line that actually reads the duration from the echo pin and saves it in the `duration` variable.

Comment: distance= duration*0.034/2; thats was the missing portion . i found it now. Thanks a lot @Majenko . now encountered another problem is my gps portion is executing after executing 80 times of printing distance in serial monitor . i just wondered why its taking too times to get inside GPS portions ?

Comment: `Can you plz rewrite it for me?` No, strong no, that's not why we come here.

Comment: extreamly sorry dear @dandavis . for the first time i have posted question in here. In rewrite i have mean which portion is need to correct . didn't mean to whole bunch of code again. Thanks to all of you for help me a lots .

Comment: no problem, welcome to stack!

Comment: To actually do the distance measurement with the ultrasonic sensor, you have to read in the echo pulse, that comes from the sensor. This is normally done with the `pulseIn()` function. Without it, you won't get any meaningful value. You have 2 portions of code: GPS and Ultrasonic distance measurement. Nice you say GPS works, try an example code for measurement with the ultrasonic sensor and understand it completely. Then you can merge the two codes